# using file created in one private actionperformed event in another

Tags: java, swing, io

I am a beginner in java and I want to create a very simple audio steganography for my project.
First I started with a frame containing three buttons, which take a text file and .wav file from the user, and one button to begin encoding. I used filechoosers with the first two buttons to input files. I want the `actionPerformed` event of my "begin" button to convert the content of these two files to bytes. After that I plan to use an LSB algorithm to hide my text file in the .wav file.
My query is how can I use the files "tfile" and "afile" in `private void beginActionPerformed` method?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class second extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form second */
    public second() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        text = new javax.swing.JButton();
        audio = new javax.swing.JButton();
        tname = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        aname = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        begin = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        text.setText("TEXT FILE");
        text.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                textActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        audio.setText("AUDIO FILE");
        audio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                audioActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        begin.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        begin.setText("BEGIN");
        begin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                beginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                         .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(87, 87, 87)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING,     javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(audio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(tname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                                .addComponent(aname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(270, 270, 270)
                        .addComponent(begin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(101, 101, 101)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(text)
                    .addComponent(tname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(audio)
                    .addComponent(aname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(begin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void textActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        JFileChooser opentext=new JFileChooser();
        opentext.showOpenDialog(this);
        int returnVal = opentext.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File tfile = opentext.getSelectedFile();
        String tfname=tfile.getName();
        tname.setText(tfname);
        // ... code that loads the contents of the file in the text area
    } 

    }                                    

    private void audioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        JFileChooser openaudio=new JFileChooser();
        openaudio.showOpenDialog(this);
        int returnVal = openaudio.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File afile = openaudio.getSelectedFile();
        aname.setText(afile.getName());

    } 
    }                                  

    private void beginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tfile);**//error here**
    }                                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new second().setVisible(true);
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tfile);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel aname;
    private javax.swing.JButton audio;
    private javax.swing.JButton begin;
    private javax.swing.JButton text;
    private javax.swing.JLabel tname;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Also, is it fine if I use only FileInputStream for converting my .txt and .wav file into bytes here, or do I need to use anything else?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to make them instance variables of the surrounding class (you should write your class names in camel-case to follow Java conventions, it helps others looking at your code):

```
public class Second extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private File afile;
    private File tfile;

    ...

    private void textActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  {                                     
        ...
        tfile = opentext.getSelectedFile();
        //set instance variable instead of local variable        
        ...
    } 



    private void audioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        ...
        afile = openaudio.getSelectedFile(); 
        //set instance variable instead of local variable
        ...
    }                                  

    private void beginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(tfile); //works now
    }
}
```

This will not work in the `main` method though, since it's in a static context. So you could add a getter method for the `File`s in your `Second` class

```
    public File getTFile() { return tfile; }
    public File getAFile() { return afile; }
```

to be able to access the files from outside the class.

Please note that both `afile` and `tfile` will only be set after you clicked the buttons and chose a file for them, otherwise these references will still be `null`. So what you want to do in your `run` method *can't* work, because you try to use tfile immediately afer showing the frame, there's no way you can have clicked and set the file reference that fast :)

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is : Put `afile` and `tfile` as class member :

```
private javax.swing.JLabel aname;
private javax.swing.JButton audio;
private javax.swing.JButton begin;
private javax.swing.JButton text;
private javax.swing.JLabel tname;

private File afile;     // put at bottom of class
private File tfile;
```

The better solution is to have another class to separate your date manipulation (model) from your view (`JFrame`)